# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/support/AbstractCacheManager

Tags: spring, maven, ehcache

**Hi all, i try include ehcache to my spring project and get this error**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/cache/support/AbstractCacheManager    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractCacheManager    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     ... 65 more

**Here is my ehcache beans**

```
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
    </bean>
```

**Here is my depencies, which can have value at this case**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

What is wrong with my dependencies/bean declaration?
i find class AbstractCacheManager but that is in non spring maven dependencies.

Comment: For starters cache is only available as of Spring 3.1 and you are mixing spring versions (3.0 and 3.2). I suggest moving all versions to 3.2.13.RELEASE instead of mixing (that is always a very bad idea and leads to difficult to debug problems).

Answer (score 0):

Open Project Properties > Deployment Assembly and add the maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The class AbstractCacheManager is not part of the 3.0.5 release of spring.

The first appearance in Maven central is version 3.1.0:

- [Maven central search](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C2%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-context%22%20AND%20fc%3A%22org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractCacheManager%22)

This is confirmed by the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html):

> Since version 3.1, Spring Framework provides support for transparently
>   adding caching into an existing Spring application....